# Would you show JSP files in a class diagram?

Tags: uml, diagram

I have developed an online web application which uses JSP's and Java classes.

I understand that Java classes would appear on a class diagram but would JSP files ?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is **no**.

Class diagrams can be utilized for different purposes, at different levels. Two very common usages are **design** and **analysis**.

1- **Analysis class diagrams** show the entities and their relationships and model your problem domain (no solution or technology involved)

2- **Design class diagrams** model your solution and may contain fabric classes. They are very close to your code. (your Java classes in this case)

Design class diagrams could have different levels of abstraction according to your need. It is very uncommon to include UI details in your class diagrams unless there is a specific reason for it.

Basically you have to make a decision on your scope, for example it is not very useful to include java library classes in your class diagrams unless there is reason for it.